# Creating Index on Foreign Table of file_fdw in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have created a foreign table for *file_fdw* in PostgreSQL to access 100m dataset. I saw that there is no way to create an index on the foreign table.

Is there any way to speed up the query on the foreign table like indexing? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. What you can do it create a materialized view (which is a copy in a PostgreSQL table) and index that.